# How to Prove that if $A$ is bounded, then $A \cdot A$ is bounded?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

> **Definition:** Let $\varnothing$ $\neq$ $A,B$ be a subset of $\Bbb R$, then we define
>   $A \cdot B$ $:=$ $\lbrace$ $a\cdot b$ | $a \in A$ , $b \in B$ $\rbrace$

---

Let $\varnothing$ $\neq$ $A$ be a subset of $\Bbb R$.

> **Question:** Prove or disprove the following statement: ''If $A$ is bounded, then $A \cdot A$ is bounded''.

Can someone help me with the proof?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Technically including $A=\emptyset$ or not does not change the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A is bounded, $\forall x \in A$, $\exists M \in \mathrm{R}^+$ such that $|x| \le M$.

> For any $a \in A\cdot A$, there exists $x,y \in A$ such that $xy=a$, hence $|xy|=|x||y|\le M\cdot M=M^2$.

Hence is bounded.

Comment: and for the lower bound, just write it with the negative numbers?

Comment: @AvivLiberman $-M$ is a lower a bound for $A$ and $M$ is a upper bound by construction.

Comment: Great thanks you all for your help! @ViktorGlombik

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: A set $A$ is bounded, if there exist two numbers $l, h$ such that for all $x \in A$ we have $l \le x \le h$. Now if $A$ is bounded, can you find the bounds for the set $A\cdot A$?